# How to get location on Android TV

Tags: java, android, kotlin, location, television

My app run Android TV but It didn't get location. 
I check on mobile. It get location is good
My code: https://github.com/phamvantruongit/Location

Comment: You should check whether the TV turned on Location settings or not? Whether the TV already supported GPS? Any tested other app with Location-based like Google, Here Map? Otherwise, we couldn't help more

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a Location provider on TV.

Extract of [the Android TV guide](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#no-gps):

> TVs are stationary, indoor devices, and do not have built-in global
>   positioning system (GPS) receivers. If your app uses location
>   information, you can still allow users to search for a location, or
>   use a static location provider such as a zip code configured during
>   the TV device setup.